# Is Hironaka's example the only known deformation of Kähler manifolds with non-Kähler central fibre?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, examples, kahler-manifolds

A well-known example in the deformation theory of compact complex manifolds is the one given by Hironaka in his 1962 paper *[An Example of a Non-Kählerian Complex-Analytic Deformation of Kählerian Complex Structures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970426)*. The construction gives rise to many interesting phenomena (see the associated [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example)), but the one that interests me most is that this was the first example of a deformation of Kähler manifolds which has limiting fibre which is not Kähler.

> Aside from Hironaka's example, are there any other explicit deformations of compact Kähler manifolds such that the central fibre is not Kähler?

Comment: When fibers are projective, on $\pi: X\to\Delta$ then the central fiber $X_0$ may not be Kahler , it is Moishezon manifold due to Dan Popovici https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-013-0449-0 , Daniel  Barlet says that this result is due to Hironaka . But Barlet gave a lot of interesting examples here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01129.pdf